# Qt c++ dependent Comboboxes and dependent label

Tags: c++, qt, csv, user-interface, combobox

I have a `data.csv` file with 2 columns. The first column contains some country names and the second column contains the capital of each country. In my user interface there is a combobox containing the names of the countries and next to it there is a label. What I want is to choose a country from the combobox and the label to show the capital of the selected country. What i have tried so far is this:

```
QFile datafile("path to data.csv");
if(datafile.open (QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    {
        QTextStream line(&datafile);
        while (!line.atEnd()){
          QString linetext=line.readLine(); // reads line from file
          const QStringList fields { linetext.split(',') };
          const QString Country { fields[0] };
          const QString Capital { fields[1] };
          ui->combobox->additem(Country);

          //add code here (or outside of while?) to show capital next to combobox

     }
}
```

[image]

I when code to show the capital is inside while, it prints the last row of thw table. When I place it outside then `fields` is not recognised. Is there a way make the file globaly usable?
Is there a more simple way?

**EDIT 12/5/2020**

That is the first part of the problem, which I got it fixed by using **thibsc**'s answer. I want to take the project further.

Lets say that the comboBox contains 2 countries, "Greece" and "Italy" so the capital cities are "Athens" and "Rome". I have 2 more `csv` files each containing the famous sights of each capital city and the file is named by the name of the city. That will be `Athens.csv` and `Rome.csv`.

So when a country is selected then the label shows the capital city next to it. I want to use the name of the city to call the corresponding `csv` file and show the list of tourist sights in a 2nd combobox. Like shown in the picture, the 1st column of each file contains the sights. The second column is optional.

[image]

The problem is that when I select a country from the 1st combobox, the 2nd combobox doesn't load the file and that's because anytime I change the county from the 1st combobox, then the 2nd loads the tourist sights from the previous selection

[image]

The full code is here

```
#include "mapproject.h"
#include "ui_mapproject.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QList>

MapProject::MapProject(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MapProject)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QFile datafile("/home/spyros/untitled/data.csv");
    if(datafile.open (QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        {
            QTextStream line(&datafile);
            while (!line.atEnd()){
              QString linetext=line.readLine(); // reads line from file
              const QStringList fields = linetext.split(',');
              ui->comboBox->addItem(fields.first(), QVariant(fields.last()));
         }
    }connect(ui->comboBox, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, [this](){
        ui->label->setText(ui->comboBox->currentData().toString());
    });
    ui->comboBox_2->setEnabled(false);
    ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(-1);
}

MapProject::~MapProject()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MapProject::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    ui->comboBox_2->setEnabled(true);
    QString City = ui->label->text();
    QFile cityfile("/home/spyros/untitled/"+City+".csv");
    if(cityfile.open (QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        {
            QTextStream line(&cityfile);
            while (!line.atEnd()){
              QString linetext=line.readLine(); // reads line from file
              const QStringList fields = linetext.split(',');
              ui->comboBox_2->addItem(fields.first(), QVariant(fields.last()));
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 fields, the first is the country and the second is the capital, so I think that the best way is to map both in the `QComboBox` item by using [`QComboBox::currentData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentData-prop):

```cpp
const QStringList fields = linetext.split(',');

// Set the item text (displayed), and the itemData (capital)
ui->combobox->additem(fields.first(), QVariant(fields.last()));
```

Now you have just to connect the signal to update your label (after your while loop):

```cpp
connect(ui->comboBox, &QComboBox::currentTextChanged, [this](){
    ui->label->setText(ui->comboBox->currentData().toString());
});
```

Comment: Your code works. That problem is solved  but another problem occured. Please check the edit. Thank you.

Comment: @mac, don't forget to clear your combobox before filling, and you can call the code inside the lambda

Comment: @mac, the lambda is the part of my answer which is like this: `[]() { }`

Comment: Clearing the combobox_2 doesn't help. I created a 2nd label just to show what the `City` variable prints. When I first select a country it doesn't print anything. When I reselect a country it prints the capital city of the previous selection. That is I think why the wrong csv file is loaded each time.

Comment: @mac, Have you put your code to fill your second combobox inside the lambda ?